# Coonection pooling in C# with ADO.NET

Tags: connection-pooling

```
How to made connection pooling in C# with ADO.NET (oledb).
I have made chnages in web.config as:
<add name="OCS"      connectionString="Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;OLEDB.NET=true;PLSQLRSet=true;
```

Connection Lifetime0; Pooling=true; Max Pool Size=25;Min Pool Size=0;Pooling'true';
    Incr Pool Size=10; Decr Pool Size=5;Connection Timeout=15; Data Source=133;User ID=itower;Password=itower"/>

Comment: Connection pooling is managed by ado.net automatically. What's your intent?

Comment: How to verify whether connection pooling is being applied or not.?

Comment: How to maintain Connection pooling at Application level rather at Session level